# Names and types in c++

Tags: c++, types, declaration, names

I'm starting my post with the questions interested for me:

**Q1**: Is it true that declaration introduced one or more name into translation unit which denote type?

**Q2**: (If answer for **Q1** is positive) How does compiler determine type of name introduced by declaration? Consider the following declaration:

This questions appears when I've started to read 3rd clause of c++ working draft.

> An entity is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type,
> class member, template, template specialization, namespace, parameter
> pack, or this.
>
> A name is a use of an identifier (2.11),
> operator-function-id (13.5), literal-operator-id (13.5.8), conversion
> function-id (12.3.2), or template-id (14.2) that denotes an entity or
> label (6.6.4, 6.1).

```
List<Observer *> *_observers;
```

This declaration introduced `_observers` into the current scope. I want to understand how does compiler determine the type of `_observers`? I'm interested in the formal algorithm described in the `c++` spec.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The specification of types is given in the standard. The algorithm to parse C++ is not given in the standard.

Comment: Each and every one of the usages of a name is described within the noted section numbers and contained within the very standard you copied the posted text from. How a compiler fulfills those usage definitions and name introductions is *entirely* up to the vendor; the standard proposes no such "algorithm" to accomplish this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Do you have a proof link to the spec?

Comment: The proof is: `extern int i;` is a declaration. Is `i` a type?

Comment: @user3521733 Ok. So what exactly entity `i` denotes?

Comment: That declaration introduces a name which denotes a variable. (Which is given as one of the possibilities in the answer below.)

Comment: @user3521733 But in the spec write the following: `A name is a use of an identifier (2.11), operator-function-id (13.5), literal-operator-id (13.5.8), conversion function-id (12.3.2), or template-id (14.2) that denotes an entity or label (6.6.4, 6.1).    An entity is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, template, template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, or this.` So variable is not an entity, thus a name cannot represent variable.

Comment: A variable can be an object. Look at 3/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaration can introduce a type, a function, a variable.

```
class A;  // This declares a type, A
A* aPtr;  // This declares a variable, aPtr
          // The type of aPtr is A*
A foo();  // This declares a function, foo.
```

In your case,

```
List<Observer*> *_Observers;  // Declares a variable, _observers.
                              // The type of _observers is List<Observer*>*.
                              // For this to be a valid declarion, the types List,
                              // a class template, and Observer must be known 
                              // (declared or defined) before the
                              // variable declaration.
```